# Connection between convergence complexity of gradient descent and complexity of exactly solving convex program?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, optimization

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Let $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be some closed convex set. Consider the following convex minimization problem:

\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbf{x} \in V} f(\mathbf{x}) \label{minconv}\tag{1}
\end{align}

Let $\mathbf{x}^*$ be the minimizer of $f$, i.e., $\mathbf{x}^* = \min_{\mathbf x \in V} f(\mathbf{x})$.

Let $\varphi:  \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be any discrete dynamical map. For any initial $\mathbf{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define the sequence $\{\mathbf{x}_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty} = \{\varphi(\mathbf{x}_{i-1})\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.

Assume that the following convergence bound holds:

\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{x}_t) - f(\mathbf{x}^*) \leq g(t)
\end{align}

where $g(t)$ is a decreasing function in $t$.

Is there a relationship between the complexity of solving the convex minimization problem $(\ref{minconv})$ and the convergence bound $g(t)$?

My question stems from a lack of understanding of the connection between the complexity of  solving a convex program exactly and solving a convex program using iterative methods. Are there convex programs that we can solve approximately fast via iterative methods (with theoretical guarantees, i.e., linear or sublinear convergence bounds) that we cannot solve in polynomial time exactly? In particular, what is the relationship between the convergence rate of (generalized) projected gradient descent on a convex program and the exact complexity of solving the same convex program.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "solving" (1)?  Representing a real number takes infinite space, so I'm guessing you mean something like outputting a $\mathbf{x}^*$ to a desired level of efficiency, but it might help to spell that out more clearly.  I suspect if you spell it out the relationship might become trivial (in $t$ steps you can compute $\mathbf{x}^*$ to within additive error $\le g(t)$, as long as the iterative sequence is guaranteed to stay within $V$) but I'm not sure whether I'm understanding the question accurately or not.

Comment: Perhaps https://mathoverflow.net/q/92939/37212 will be of interest?

Comment: Oops thanks for the comment the function in the difference inequality was supposed to be f. Fixed it. The inequality must be correct now since $\mathbf{x}^*$ is the minimizer of f.

Comment: I guess I'm not really concerned by space considerations, i.e., can a real number be represented or not. For instance, from the question you linked, we know that a large number of convex programs are solvable exactly in polynomial time through interior point methods. My question is, is there a relation between the convergence rates of iterative processes such as gradient descent and the computational complexity of solving a convex program exactly.

Comment: OK.  Why isn't the answer trivial, namely that in running time $O(t)$ you can solve to within additive error $\le g(t)$, so long as $\varphi$ is guaranteed to keep you within $V$ and $\varphi$ can be computed in $O(1)$ time?  I suspect I must be missing something, as if the answer was that easy you would have already noticed, so I wonder what I'm missing.

Comment: The iterative process never gets to the exact solution, it only gets there in the limit as $t \to \infty$! So it is not an exact computation but an approximation! :) So if we wanted to get the exact answer (theoretically) we would have to run the iterative process indefinitely. However, solving the program via a method such as an interior point method gives you an exact solution in finite time.

Comment: I think many methods for convex optimization also give only an approximation, not an exact computation.  My knowledge on this is pretty sparse, but I think this applies to interior point methods, SDPs, to Newton's-method-based algorithms, and more.  Are you sure that interior point methods give an exact solution in finitely many steps?  I could be confused.  Anyway, I think it would be helpful to [edit] your question to define what you mean by "solve".  If you mean "output an exact solution (an approximation is not good enough)" I think it might be useful to specify that in the question.

Comment: Ah! I think you might be right! For some reason this was the mental image in my head but I think I am wrong. Let me see if I can rephrase the question or else I am gonna delete it!